# I'm using semantic UI form validation with regex rule 'regExp[/(.*[0-9 \\-]){23}$/]' .It is working fine on other devices except iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, regex, semantic-ui

**I have the following code below which takes card number as input for example 5077-1200-5007-3284-951.
The card number is valid for all devices/browsers except iOS.
Also, please let me know I can use another regex for the same pattern.**

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/semantic.min.css"></link>
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/semantic.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="field example">
<form class="ui form">
    <div class="field">
      <label>Card Number</label>
      <input id="name" name="cardNumber" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="ui submit button">Submit</div>
    <div class="ui error message"></div>
  </form>
</div>
</body> 
<script>
  $('.field.example form')
  .form({
    on: 'blur',
    fields: {
      empty: {
        identifier  : 'empty',
        rules: [
          {
            type   : 'empty',
            prompt : 'Please enter a value'
          }
        ]
      },
      cardNumber: {
                        identifier: 'cardNumber',
                        rules: [{
                            type: 'empty',
                            prompt: 'Required'
                        },
            {
                            type: 'regExp[/(.*[0-9 \-]){23}/]',
                            prompt: 'Invalid'
                        }]

                    },
      checkbox: {
        identifier  : 'checkbox',
        rules: [
          {
            type   : 'checked',
            prompt : 'Please check the checkbox'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  })
;
  </script>
<html>
```

Comment: @Mandy8055 It worked for iOS, but now if I am entering digits more than the expected input it still allowing without error (Sample I/p: 5077-1200-5007-3284-951111). Can we limit the size in the same as well ?

Comment: @Mandy8055 Thanks a lot buddy. It worked as expected :-)

Comment: Yes sure. It is the answer

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```
^(?:\d{4}-){4}\d{3}$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`^, $`** - Represents start and end of the line respectively.
- **`(?:\d{4}-){4}`** - Represents a non-capturing group matching four digits followed by a `-` exactly 4 times.
- **`\d{3}`** - Matching the digit exactly 3 times.

---

[image: Pictorial representation]

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/sZsRrQ/6)

Comment: Nice explanation and the drawing has made it even more lucid!

Comment: Thanks sir @ArvindKumarAvinash for the motivation...